# Не ищет русские слова/буквы

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, denwer

Всем привет,делал поиск для сайта все хорошо работает, кроме того что он отказывается искать именно русские запросы и выдает ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот Search.php, но я думаю не в нем ошибку так как цифры и англ.слова ищет отлично.

```
include_once('DbConnect.php');

 class Search extends DbConnect
{
/** @var null|string */
private $_table = null;

/** @var  PDO */
private $_connection;

/** @var  array */
private $_query = array();

/** @var bool|string */
private $_alias = false;

/** @var bool */
private $_one = false;

/** @var bool */
private $_where = false;

/**
 * Search constructor.
 * @param bool|string $_table
 */
public function __construct($_table = false)
{

    if (!$this->_checkDB()) {
        return array('error' => 'Failed to connect to DB');
    }

    if (!$_table) {
        return array('error' => 'Table name is not specified');
    }

    $this->_table = $_table;
    $this->_alias = $this->_getTableAlias($this->_table);
}

/**
 * @param string $_fields
 * @return $this
 */
public function select($_fields = '*')
{
    if (is_array($_fields)) {
        $_fields = implode(', ', $_fields);
    }

    $this->_query[] = "select {$_fields} from {$this->_table} as {$this->_alias}";

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $_type
 * @param bool $_table
 * @param array $_conditions
 * @return $this
 * @internal param bool $_alias
 */
public function _join($_type = 'left', $_table = false, $_conditions = array())
{
    switch ($_type) {
        case 'left':
        case 'right':
        case 'inner':
            $_alias = $this->_getTableAlias($_table);
            $this->_query[] = "{$_type} join `{$_table}` as {$_alias} on";

            foreach ($_conditions as $_condition) {
                switch ($_condition['joinWith']) {
                    case 'this':
                        foreach ($_condition['fields'] as $_field => $_field_condition) {
                            $this->_query[] = "{$_condition['type']} {$_alias}.{$_field}{$_condition['operation']}'{$_field_condition}'";
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        foreach ($_condition['fields'] as $_field => $_field_condition) {
                            $this->_query[] = "{$_condition['type']} {$_field_condition}{$_condition['operation']}" .
                                "{$this->_getTableAlias($_condition['joinWith'])}.{$_field}";
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            break;
        default:

            break;
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param array $_conditions
 * @return $this
 */
public function where($_conditions = array())
{

    if (is_array($_conditions)) {
        $_request = array();

        if (!$this->_where) {
            $_request[] = 'where';
            $this->_where = true;
        }

        foreach ($_conditions as $_field => $_value) {

            if (array_key_exists('type', $_value)) {
                $_request[] = $_value['type'];
            }

            if (array_key_exists('operation', $_value)) {
                $_request[] = "{$this->_alias}.{$_value['field']}{$_value['operation']}{$_value['value']}";
            } else {
                $_request[] = "{$this->_alias}.{$_value['field']} {$_value['value']}";
            }
        }

        $this->_query[] = implode(' ', $_request);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return array|object
 */
public function toArray()
{
    try {

        $_query = $this->_connection
            ->query(implode(' ', $this->_query));

        return $this->_preFormat($_query->fetchAll());
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        return array('error' => $exception->getMessage());
    }
}

private function _preFormat($_data = array())
{
    $_results = array();
    $_columns = array();

    foreach ($_data as $_record) {

        if (empty($_columns)) {

            $_column_index = 0;

            foreach ($_record as $_key => $_value) {
                if (!in_array($_key, $_columns) && is_string($_key)) {
                    $_columns[$_column_index] = $_key;
                    $_column_index++;
                }
            }
        }

        $_object = array();

        foreach ($_columns as $_column) {
            $_object[$_column] = $_record[$_column];
        }

        if ($this->_one) {
            $_results = (object)$_object;
        } else {
            $_results[] = (object)$_object;
        }
    }

    return $_results;
}

public function limit($_limit = 1, $_offset = 0)
{
    $this->_query[] = "limit {$_limit} offset {$_offset}";

    return $this;
}

public function first($_field = 'id')
{
    $this->_query[] = "order by {$this->_alias}.{$_field} asc";
    $this->limit();

    $this->_one = true;

    return $this->toArray();
}

public function last($_field = 'id')
{
    $this->_query[] = "order by {$this->_alias}.{$_field} desc";
    $this->limit();

    $this->_one = true;

    return $this->toArray();
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
private function _checkDB()
{
    try {
        $this->_connection = DbConnect::getInstance();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns table alias
 *
 * @param bool $_table
 * @return bool|string
 */
private function _getTableAlias($_table = false)
{
    if (!$_table) {
        return false;
    }

    $_table_alias = explode('_', $_table);

    if (count($_table_alias) > 1) {
        $_alias = '';

        foreach ($_table_alias as $_word) {
            $_alias .= $_word[0];
        }

        return $_alias;
    } else {
        return $_table[0];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL по умолчанию для текста стоит кодировка latin1. Для того, что бы работать с кириллицей нужно поменять на utf8. 
[Тут написано как сделать utf8](http://gahcep.github.io/blog/2013/01/05/mysql-utf8/)

Comment: Да, но у меня уже UTF-8